# Gitlab CI/CD: use multiple when conditions

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api, cicd

I have like this gitlab ci cd configuration file:

```
image: docker:git

stages:  
  - develop
  - production
default:
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk upgrade && apk add git curl

deploy:
    stage: develop
    script: 
      - echo "Hello World"
  
backup:
    stage: develop    
    when:
      - manual
      - on_success

remove:
    stage: develop    
    when:
      - delayed
      - on_success
    start_in: 30 minutes
```

In my case job `deploy` runs automaticaly and job `backup` must runs manually only when successfully completed job `deploy`. But in my case this configuration doesn't works and I get error with message:

**Found errors in your** `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

jobs:backup when should be one of:

- on_success
- on_failure
- always
- manual
- delayed

How I can use multiple `when` option arguments in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't because `when` does not expect an array. You can work around it though with [needs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs). But this solution does only work if you run your jobs in different stages.

```
image: docker:git

stages:  
  - deploy
  - backup
  - remove

deploy:develop:
  stage: deploy
  script: 
    - exit 1
  
backup:develop:
  stage: backup  
  script:
    - echo "backup"  
  when: manual
  needs: ["deploy:develop"]

remove:develop:
  stage: remove
  script:
    - echo "remove"    
  when: delayed
  needs: ["backup:develop"]
  start_in: 30 minutes
```